# Run API tests in docker using http://localhost:port

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

There is an app for book flights and our team is implementing integrations to interact with the flight booking app. So now there is a need to test their APIs in CI environment.
Therefore, I have created a Dockerfile in my API testing framework:

> ```
> FROM golang:1.13
>
> ADD . /app
>
> WORKDIR /app
>
> RUN go mod download
>
> CMD ["make", "test", "$URL=", "$INTEGRATION=", "$TESTTYPE=", "$TAGS="]
> ```

And also I have created a docker-compose.yml file in the integration repo which I should test:

> ```
> version: '3'
>
> services:
>   tests:
>     image: int-tests:latest
>     environment:
>       - URL=http://localhost:3000/
>       - INTEGRATION=pitane
>       - TESTTYPE=integration
>       - TAGS=quotes
> ```

I have tried to build and run the integration tests using localhost. Locally I can do it without using docker. But inside docker I can't use localhost link of the integration to call their endpoints. Is there any way to do it?
This is the error message that I'm getting:

```
msg="Post http://localhost:3000/v1/quote: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3000: connect: connection refusedUnable to get response"
```

Comment: Where is the actual system under test running; does `make test` launch it, or is it in another container?  Is the relevant fragment of your Makefile important to the question?

Comment: Yes. I'm executing tests using Makefile.

Answer (score 2):

> msg="Post http://localhost:3000/v1/quote: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3000:
>   connect: connection refusedUnable to get response"

You are trying to connect to the container itself. Use host ip address or `network_mode: "host"`

**UPD**

You can find out your host ip with `ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'` and then use this ip in the `URL` environment variable.

Or you can get rid of network isolation of the container at all setting `network_mode: "host"` in docker-compose.yml (not preferred way though)

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

In this case localhost will denote host machine localhost.

Also you can use `host.docker.internal` if you use Mac (not preferred way)
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail? like how to do it or where to put it `network_mode: "host"`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have added the `network_mode: host` and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

1. At docker file expose appropriate port (port, others will connect to your service)

```
EXPOSE 80
```

2. If you want to access that started container at hosting machine you have to map that port to your hosting machine. You do it with docker command:

```
docker run -p 80:80 ....
```

or with docker compose:

```
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```